# Can Shaytaan appear like one of the Prophets?

Tags: prophets, dream

As is known, Shaytaan cannot appear in our dreams in the form of Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon Him):

> مَنْ رَآنِي فِي الْمَنَامِ فَقَدْ رَآنِي فَإِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ لاَ
> يَتَمَثَّلُ بِي
>
> He who saw me in a dream in fact saw me, for the satan does not appear
> in my form
>
> [Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/urn/360930)

So my question is, are the other Prophets (peace be upon them) like our Prophet in the sense that Shaytaan cannot appear like them in our dreams? or is this only for Muhammad (Peace and blessings be upon Him)

Comment: http://islamqa.info/en/ref/47782

Comment: this is almost duplicate of this little more general question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/how-to-know-this-dream-is-really-roya

Answer (score 1):

The companions of the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) knew him by face, so if they see him then its no doubt [that the dream is NOT from the Devil](http://sunnah.com/urn/360930). As we do not know him by face, we can not be sure that it is indeed him that we saw. Same is the case with other prophets.

So it's better not to make any judgement on such dream, but rely on Allah's and our Prophet's guidance and our God-given intellect.

Answer (score 0):

Can Satan appear like the prophets?
Of course, the devil can not appear in the form of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) and other prophets. .
Satan does not appear not only as a prophet and imams, but also as pure Shiites and saints. The Messenger of God said: The devil does not appear in my face, nor in the case of any of his guardians, nor in the case of any of his Shiites.
The appearance of the devil does not mean that he goes out of his true nature and changes his nature, but it means that he is felt in different ways in the power of human sense and perception, without changing his nature.

Ref: https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%AB%D9%84-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%B3%D9%85-%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%86/138964