# What conditions can violate seeing Prophet Muhammad in ones dream

Tags: prophet-muhammad, dream

Is there anything, a condition or a situation, that can make a dream about seeing the prophet untrue or just an imagination or a thought from shaytan?

Comment: can't understand your question

Comment: How do you that you saw him. Do you know how he looks like?

Comment: Dont know how he looks like. I'm not claiming anything just curious. What i wanna know is lets say that such a dream is true only if it happens at a certain time of the night (like before fajr) or is it true only if you sleep with wudo etc?

Comment: do not you know who is who in dream without any recognising or even without seeing his face?! but it is so, we just know it in dream, it is part of dream.

Comment: see http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/how-to-know-this-dream-is-really-roya

Answer (score 3):

The companions of the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) knew him by face, so if they see him then its no doubt that the dream is NOT from the Devil. As we do not know him by face, we can not be sure that it is indeed him that we saw. So it's better not to make any judgement on such dream, but rely on Allah's and our Prophet's guidance and our God-given intellect.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, Sahaba will undoubtedly confirm if it was him as the Shaytan cannot take His form. But it doesnt mean that the prophect wont come in someones dream other than a sahabi!

Comment: Yes, he can come but we can not know whether its actually him or not

Answer (score 0):

Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) has said that it is impossible for shaytan to take His form in someone's dream. That is authentic Hadith. Do not doubt the sayings of Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم). If someone doubts his sayings, he becomes disbeliever and whoever tells a lie about Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) he will be punished here and in the hereafter.

Now to your question: What are the conditions that violate vision of Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) in dream?

One is lying; a liar is forbidden from seeing Him (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم). But every thing happens or does not happens is by ALLAH's Will. (citation needed)

A person who sends salutations (darood sharif) upon the Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) with deep love will continue to get closer to the Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) and will eventually see Him in his dreams. In the dream, they will KNOW that it is Prophet (صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم) as it is said: Momin's spirit knows other momin's spirit. (citation needed)

This is a hint to understand what happens in the spiritual life.

I ask forgiveness if there is any mistake from ALLAH AL-REHMAN.

Comment: Salam, please add some citations to back up your answer, thank you.