# Can a person know he or she is going to Jannah or Jahannam in dream?

Tags: sunni, dream

For example if Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) comes in a dream and says you will goto Heaven or any similar dream like that.So can a person get a good news of Jannah  in dream or bad news of Jahannam in this life through a dream ?

Comment: How would you know it was the Prophet Muhammad in the dream when you have never seen him (PBUH)? :)

Comment: Anyone can see Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) in the dream and we can recognize him by just using our common sense. For example in dreams we know certain things automatically.

Comment: Could you provide references for that? This might help the one answering your question.

Comment: Yes you can see your place in Jannah in a dream but that is very rare!. You can also see if you will die soon.

Comment: @Kilise You can see the Prophet in a dream. The Prophet said: Whoever sees me in a dream will see me when he is awake; the Shaytaan cannot take my shape.

Comment: @Casanova that Hadith was to the sahaba who knew how he looked.

Comment: He said "whoever"

Comment: Can you understand arabic?

Comment: @Casanova I was on my phone, see my answer.

Comment: @Casanova So should I conclude that a person in his or her dream can know if they are going to Jannah ?

Comment: @Kilise There are many Muslims who are not from ashab so yeah they have not seen Rasulullahi SalAllahu alayhi waalihi wasallam but Alhamdulillah some have seen Him peace be upon him in their dreams.

Comment: @Faqirah Even if someone has seen him in their dreams they **cannot** back it up and know it was him for sure. Also I do not think that Hadith are for all people in general rather for the sahaba who knew him. I have mentioned that in my answer, no need to get into a discussion.

Comment: @YoungMuslim1000 see my answer and leave a comment on it if you think something is missing. If you decided you already have an answer to your question then you could answer it yourself here.

Comment: @Kilise its a good answer. I was just curious to know if someone can really know through their dreams that they will goto Jannah. But I didn't get a satisfying answer regarding my question. I know a good dream is from Allah S.W.T so if a person sees Jannah in his dream or any sign related to Jannah then can a person conclude he is going to Jannah?

Comment: @Kilise will you edit your answer for my above question?

Comment: @YoungMuslim1000 I will inshallah as soon as I get some more time. My conclusion is intended to be a "no", but i will come to that in my answer.

Comment: I already asked similar question here https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56909/is-there-any-hadith-which-says-you-may-get-glad-tidings-of-jannah-in-dreams

Answer (score 1):

There are certain ahadith speaking about seeing the Prophet in a dream. For instance:

> مَنْ رَآنِي فِي الْمَنَامِ فَقَدْ رَآنِي، فَإِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ لاَ يَتَخَيَّلُ بِي
>
> Whoever has seen me in a dream, then no doubt, he has seen me, for Satan cannot imitate my shape.
>   - https://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/13

And:

> مَنْ رَآنِي فِي الْمَنَامِ فَسَيَرَانِي فِي الْيَقَظَةِ، وَلاَ يَتَمَثَّلُ الشَّيْطَانُ بِي ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عَبْدِ اللَّهِ قَالَ ابْنُ سِيرِينَ إِذَا رَآهُ فِي صُورَتِهِ‏.‏
>
> Whoever sees me in a dream will see me in his wakefulness, and Satan cannot imitate me in shape." Abu `Abdullah said, "Ibn Seereen said, '**Only if he sees the Prophet (ﷺ) in his (real) shape**.
>   -  https://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/12

---

To understand this, we first need to understand how the science of hadith works or was intended to work. As known, a hadith is a saying that we except go back to the Prophet by a chain of narrations.

Imagine the prophet (saw) speaking to his companions, telling them "whoever  sees me in a dream has seen me, because Satan cannot take my form."
The sahaba, who knows how the Prophet looks, will now mention this hadith to other people (in the chain), they will then mention it further until a point, people no longer know how he looks.

If you do not know how the prophet looks, you cannot draw the conclusion saying I saw the Prophet. As you see in the above hadith; **"Ibn Seereen said, 'Only if he sees the Prophet (ﷺ) in his (real) shape"**. How do you know this is the real shape of the Prophet, when you never actually have seen him? You might say, "well Satan cannot imitate and takes his shape", but even though this is true how do you know that Satan isn't imitating another shape, because you don't know his (pbuh) true shape?

Therefore, we who never have seen the Prophet, will never be able to differentiate and know if the person in the dream is the Prophet or not. *The prophet never mentioned that we will see him. He was speaking to his companions who knew him.*

**With this understanding, its not possible to draw any conclusions from a dream, when one cannot be sure who one saw in the dream in the first place.**

---

*You will find different of opinions in this matter, for instance [this](https://islamqa.info/en/47782), and [this](http://www.alsunna.org/Can-the-Person-see-Prophet-Muhammad-in-his-dream.html).* But very few mentions the reality that you cannot differentiate and know for a fact who you have seen in your dream. You will also find minor opinions about [dream interpretations only are for Prophets](https://youtu.be/yMRF0TXxMMQ?t=5m19s) and ain't called dreams but rather *visions*.

*There seems that some argue that we got some descriptions of how the Prophet looked in the ahadith, and by that they somehow could draw the conclusion that it was he who they saw in their dream. This argument is very very weak and bad, because the description we have cannot in any way give us a picture of how the Prophet really looked. The description could fit tens of thousands different shapes. See the description here: "[How did the Prophet Muhammad look like?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39780/15201)".*

Relevant: "[What conditions can violate seeing Prophet Muhammad in ones dream](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/8361/15201)"

Comment: Down-voter: "[When should I vote down?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." - Please leave a comment why you down-voted this question. **Islam SE isn't a place where** one down-votes a question just because one disagrees of ones opinion.

Comment: I remember that some scholars said this ahadith apply only for the sahaba as they have seen the prophet and could recognise him.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If you could find references for that, I could add that to the answer, which would backup my explanation even more.

Comment: As far as i recall it was stated in an answer on islamqa.

Comment: This answer is purely opinion based. Can you back your answer with what the scholars said?

Comment: I remember bukhari, ibn hajar and ibn sireen saying a very different thing

Comment: You could post an answer with the other point of view if you wish. I mentioned in the answer that there are different of opinions and linked to some relevant answers. But as Medi1Saif mentions he remembers some scholars said this only apply for the sahaba, which basically is what i've answered. But, then even though I cannot back up scholars sayings, could you logically explain how someone can see the prophet when they don't even know how he looks? How do they know it is the prophet when they never seen him? Its Impossible to know. @Casanova

Comment: We know how the prophet looks from the Hadiths

Answer (score 0):

You can see him in dreams but you have to know how he looka by reading hadith and words of sahabas that described him sources, he is neither tall nor short, hes neither dark or light, etc, and shaytan might come to you in other form and tell you that he is Prophet.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site to learn more about how this site works. Please cite sources and thoroughly answer the question asked.

Comment: Additionally, this is incorrect. Hadith say that he was white ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/) 2340, 2343), as were his armpits (Sahih al-Bukhari [390](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/42), 807, 1030, 6341; Sahih Muslim [495](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/), 895; etc.), his cheeks ([Sunan an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/13/) 1317, 1323, 1324; Sahih Muslim 582), his [stomach](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/152), his [forearms](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/21/118), his [thigh](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/23), and his [shins](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/281).